# POST Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm working on an old project that wasn't developed by me at first. I need to make an Ajax request so that the values contained in the fields (more on that later) be sent to a php script which will then return their values into the correct td.
Here is the JavaScript/jQuery code.

```
$(function () 
{   

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'envoi_dispo_semaine.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () 
            {
                alert('Le planning a été mis à jour.');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function date()
    {
        Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
            var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
            var today = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate());
            var dayOfYear = ((today - onejan +1)/86400000);
            return Math.ceil(dayOfYear/7)
        };

        var today = new Date();
        var t = today.getWeek();
    })

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

        jDispo  = {};
        jCharge = {};
        jSolde  = {};
        var d = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var s = 0;

        jQuery('.DISPO').each(function()
        {
            jDispo[d] = jQuery(this).val();
            d++;
        });

        jQuery(".CHARGE").change(function()
        {
            var totalCharge = 0;
            if(jQuery(".CHARGE").length > 0)
            {
                jQuery(".CHARGE").each(function() 
                {
                    jCharge[c] = jQuery(this).val();
                    c++;
                    totalCharge = totalCharge + jQuery(this).val(); 
                });

            }
            jQuery('.SOLDE').each(function()
            {
                jSolde[s] = jQuery(this).val();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'post',
                    url:'check_charge.php',
                    data:{charge : jCharge[s],solde : jSolde[s],dispo : jDispo[s],action:"update_site"},
                    success: function() 
                    {
                        $('jSolde[s]').empty();
                        $('jSolde[s]').append();
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    }
                });
                s++;
            });
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if ($("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(2) td:contains('-')").length) 
        {
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(2) td:contains('-')").css('background', '#CCFF00');
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(2) td:contains('-')").css('font-color', 'black');
        }
        if ($("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(5) td:contains('-')").length) 
        {
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(5) td:contains('-')").css('background', '#CCFF00');
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(5) td:contains('-')").css('font-color', 'black');
        }
        if ($("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(8) td:contains('-')").length) 
        {
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(8) td:contains('-')").css('background', '#CCFF00');
            $("#tab_projets table tbody tr:eq(8) td:contains('-')").css('font-color', 'black');
        }
    });
});
```

And here is check_charges.php:

```
<?php
   include('connexion_db.php');

   $charge   = $_POST['charge'];
   $dispo    = $_POST['dispo'];
   $solde    = $_POST['solde']; //I'll need this one later on.

$res = $dispo - $charge;
echo $res;
?>
```

I also have some php code that allows me to generate a table (it's in the same file as the javascript):

```
<thead>
            <?php
                echo "  <td colspan=2>Semaine n°</td>
                        <td>Retard</td>";
                for ($i=$numerosemaine; $i <= $numerosemaine + $longueurAff; $i++) 
                {
                    echo "<form action=\"envoi_dispo_semaine.php\" method=\"post\">
                            <td>
                                <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"semaine_id\" value=\"".$i."\" />".$i."</td>";
                }

            ?>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 

                foreach($users as &$myUser)
                {
                        echo "  <tr class=".$myUser.">
                                    <td width=66% rowspan=3><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"login\" value=\"".$myUser."\" onblur=\"updateCharge\"/>".$myUser."</td>
                                    <td width=34%>Disponibilité</td>
                                    <td rowspan=3></td>
                            ";
                                    for ($i=$numerosemaine; $i <= $numerosemaine + $longueurAff; $i++) 
                                    {
                                        $req = "
                                                SELECT Nb_max_jours FROM Dispo_par_semaine WHERE login = '".$myUser."' AND semaine_id = ".$i;
                                        $query = requete_is_plancharges($req);
                                        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
                                        $affichageDispo = $row[0];
                                        if ($affichageDispo == "") 
                                        {
                                            $affichageDispo = 3;
                                        }
                                        echo "  
                                                <td>
                                                    <input class=\"DISPO\" type=\"number\" name=\"disponibilite[]\" value=".$affichageDispo." min=\"0\" max=\"5\" step=\"0.5\" class=\"input\"/>
                                                </td>
                                            ";
                                    }
                                    echo"
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=".$myUser.">
                                    <td width=34%>Charge</td>";
                                    for ($i=$numerosemaine; $i <= $numerosemaine + $longueurAff; $i++) 
                                    { 
                                        $reqTache = "
                                            SELECT tache_id 
                                            FROM Tache 
                                            WHERE ebi_id = ".$ebi."
                                             AND demande_id = ".$demande."
                                             AND action_id = ".$action;
                                        $resultatTache_id = requete_is_plancharges($reqTache);
                                        $maTache = mysql_fetch_object($resultatTache_id);

                                        $req_Charge = "
                                        SELECT COUNT(charge) as charge_tache
                                        FROM Charge_par_tache 
                                        WHERE tache_id   =".$maTache->tache_id.
                                        " AND semaine_id =".$i.
                                        " AND login      = '".$myUser."'";

                                        $resultat_requete_Charge = mysql_fetch_object(requete_is_plancharges($req_Charge));

                                        if ($resultat_requete_Charge->charge_tache > 0) 
                                        {
                                            $req = "
                                                SELECT Charge_par_tache.charge 
                                                FROM Charge_par_tache, Tache 
                                                WHERE   Charge_par_tache.tache_id = Tache.tache_id
                                                    AND Tache.ebi_id = ".$ebi." 
                                                    AND Tache.demande_id = ".$demande." 
                                                    AND Tache.action_id = ".$action."
                                                    AND Charge_par_tache.login = '".$myUser."' 
                                                    AND Charge_par_tache.semaine_id = ".$i;

                                            $Charge = mysql_fetch_object(requete_is_plancharges($req));



                                        } else
                                        {
                                            $Charge->charge = "";
                                        }
                                        echo "  <input type = \"hidden\" name = \"tache_id\" value=".$maTache->tache_id.">
                                                    <td class=\"CHARGE\">";
                                                        $query = requete_is_plancharges($req);
                                                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                                                        $affichageCharge = $row[0];
                                                        echo " <input class=\"CHARGE\" type=\"number\" name=\"charge[]\" value=".$Charge->charge." min=\"0\" step=\"0.5\"/>
                                                    </td>";
                                    }
                                    echo"
                                </tr>
                                <tr class=".$myUser.">
                                    <td width=34%>Solde</td>";
                                    for ($i=$numerosemaine; $i <= $numerosemaine + $longueurAff; $i++) 
                                    {
                                        $req1 = "
                                                SELECT charge FROM Charge_par_tache WHERE login = '".$myUser."' AND semaine_id = ".$i;
                                        $req2 = "
                                                SELECT Nb_max_jours FROM Dispo_par_semaine WHERE login = '".$myUser."' AND semaine_id = ".$i;
                                        $query1 = requete_is_plancharges($req1);
                                        $row1 = mysql_fetch_row($query1);
                                        $query2 = requete_is_plancharges($req2);
                                        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
                                        $solde=$row2[0]-$row1[0];
                                        echo "<td class=\"SOLDE\"><input type=\"hidden\" class=\"SOLDE\" value=".$solde."/> ".$solde."</td>";
                                    }
                                        ?>
                                </tr>
                                        <?php
                }
            ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Mise à jour"></p>
        </form>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to retrieve $res. I'm just starting Ajax so I really don't know what to do, and couldn't find the answer on the Internet as I use a js array to store my values.

Comment: You should post more code since we can not see when/where `check_charges.php` is called

Comment: I would start by looking at this in console. Do you see any errors? Also make sure those values are getting sent look at the network tab and look at the url you are passing to your .php file.

Comment: @prola There aren't any errors on the console and I can see the values getting sent

Comment: @sglessard check_charges.php is called in $.ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem you want to get the response value of "check_charges.php", that it is the $res value, isn't it? The value will be returned in the first parameter of success function of your ajax.

Your code:

```
jQuery('.SOLDE').each(function()
{
    jSolde[s] = jQuery(this).val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:'post',
        url:'check_charge.php',
        data:{charge : jCharge[s],solde : jSolde[s],dispo : jDispo[s],action:"update_site"},
        success: function(data) 
        {
            // Store where you want the data value
            alert('res value: ' + data);
            $('jSolde[s]').empty();
            $('jSolde[s]').append();
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        }
    });
    s++;
});
```

I hope I have helped you.